# How to extract content in between an opening and a closing bracket?

Tags: javascript, regex, match, lookbehind, capturing-group

I am trying to split a string into an array of text contents which each are present within the `[@` and `]` delimiters. Just characters in between `[@`and `]` are allowed to match. Being provided with a string like ...

```
const stringA = '[@Mary James], [@Jennifer John] and [@Johnny Lever[@Patricia Robert] are present in the meeting and [@Jerry[@Jeffery Roger] is absent.'
```

... the following result is expected ...

```
[
  'Mary James',
  'Jennifer John',
  'Patricia Robert',
  'Jeffery Roger'
]
```

Any logic which leads to the expected outcome can be used.

A self search for a solution brought up the following applied regex ...

```
stringA.match(/(?<=\[@)[^\]]*(?=\])/g);
```

But the result doesn't fulfill the requirements because the array features the following items ...

```
[
  'Mary James',
  'Jennifer John',
  'Johnny Lever[@Patricia Robert',
  'Jerry[@Jeffery Roger'
]
```

Comment: Why doesn't it fulfill your requirement? What is it getting wrong?

Comment: [`/\[@(?<content>[^\[\]]+)\]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/v234aT/1) ... `[ ...'[@Mary James], [@Jennifer John] and [@Johnny Lever[@Patricia Robert] are present in the meeting and [@Jerry[@Jeffery Roger] is absent.'.matchAll(/\[@(?<content>[^\[\]]+)\]/g) ].map(({ groups: { content } }) => content);`

Comment: @JustinMorgan ... the OP's regex does not feature the opening bracket within the character class, thus changing the OP's `/(?<=\[@)[^\]]*(?=\])/g` to `(?<=\[@)[^\[\]]*(?=\])` already solves the OP's problem for most environments not including safari browsers due to the lookbehind which is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP's regex does not feature the opening bracket within the negated character class, thus changing the OP's `/(?<=\[@)[^\]]*(?=\])/g` to `(?<=\[@)[^\[\]]*(?=\])` already solves the OP's problem for most environments [not including safari browsers due to the lookbehind which is not supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind).

Solution based on a regex ... [`/\[@(?<content>[^\[\]]+)\]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/v234aT/1) ... with a [named capture group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) ...

```js
const sampleText = '[@Mary James], [@Jennifer John] and [@Johnny Lever[@Patricia Robert] are present in the meeting and [@Jerry[@Jeffery Roger] is absent.'

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/v234aT/1]
const regXCapture = /\[@(?<content>[^\[\]]+)\]/g;

console.log(
  Array.from(
    sampleText.matchAll(regXCapture)
  ).map(
    ({ groups: { content } }) => content
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Close, just missing the exclusion of `[`:

```js
stringA.match(/(?<=\[@)[^\[\]]*(?=\])/g);
//                       ^^ exclude '[' as well as ']'
```

Comment: ... see my comment on safari browsers not supporting regex [lookbehind](https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind)